# Delete branch with jgit not working as expected

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, jgit

I am trying to delete a branch in my repo using jgit.

```
DeleteBranchCommand command = git.branchDelete();
command.setBranchNames("myBranch");
command.setForce(true);
try {
    List<String> deletedBranches = new ArrayList<String>();
deletedBranches = command.call();
System.out.println(deletedBranches.toString());
} catch (GitAPIException e) {
throw new MyInternalErrorException("Error while deleting branch [" + branchName + "]", e);
}
```

The value of `deletedBranches` will be `[myBranch]`

If I check if the branch is still in the repo:

```
git.getRepository().getRef("myBranch");
```

I will get `true`.
And this is because cf to jgit javadoc:

`getRef(name)`

> **name** the name of the ref to lookup. May be a short-hand form, e.g.
>   "master" which is is automatically expanded to "refs/heads/master" if
>   "refs/heads/master" already exists.

It is checking for "refs/heads/myBranch" instead of "myBranch".

Moreover, if I will run the `deleteBranch` command the second time, the value for `deletedBranches` will be `[refs/heads/myBranch]`.

Can someone explain why is this happening and how can I solve this issue?
Thank you.

**Update**

After debugging inside the jgit code, I've noticed that

```
String fullName = currentRef.getName();
```

https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/a76a4acf87952249b94f4be29614565541eb8c46/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/DeleteBranchCommand.java#L133

returns "myBranch" instead of "heads/refs/myBranch" thus it is not executing this piece of code:

```
                if (fullName.startsWith(Constants.R_HEADS)) {
                    String shortenedName = fullName
                            .substring(Constants.R_HEADS.length());
                    // remove upstream configuration if any
                    final StoredConfig cfg = repo.getConfig();
                    cfg.unsetSection(
                            ConfigConstants.CONFIG_BRANCH_SECTION,
                            shortenedName);
                    cfg.save();
                }
```

https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/a76a4acf87952249b94f4be29614565541eb8c46/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/DeleteBranchCommand.java#L158-L167

Answer (score 0):

It could be similar to [`git branch -d`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch), which will refuse to delete a branch not fully merged in its upstream branch.

That is why the examples you see in [`org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/BranchCommandTest`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/64b0531c35674df21ed02ab96d5f5bc6f5af7052/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/BranchCommandTest.java#L287-L330) are using `setForce(true)` (like a `git branch -D`):

```
List<String> deleted = git.branchDelete().setBranchNames("ForDelete")
            .setForce(true).call();
```

Comment: I agree. That's why I am using `command.setForce(true);` before calling the command, so it should be equivalent to `git branch -D`

Comment: @victorsc and there is no exception when calling the command? (since you can wrap it in a '`try`' '`catch`', as in https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/64b0531c35674df21ed02ab96d5f5bc6f5af7052/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/BranchCommandTest.java#L293-L298)

Comment: I simplified a bit the code in my question. Actually I have it wrapped in    try {
   deletedBranches = command.call();
  System.out.println(deletedBranches.toString());
  } catch (GitAPIException e) {
   throw new MyInternalErrorException("Error while deleting branch [" + branchName + "]", e);
  }

Comment: what I do not understand at all is why the first time the command is deleting `[myBranch]` and the second time `[refs/heads/myBranch]`

Comment: @victorsc maybe because it doesn't find mybranch the second time , so it will try the extended name.

Comment: then how is it possible to pass only "ForDelete" as parameter in the delete command but actually to remove Constants.R_HEADS + "ForDelete" https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/64b0531c35674df21ed02ab96d5f5bc6f5af7052/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/BranchCommandTest.java#L299-L302 This is exactly what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @victorsc maybe because on the first call, the branch still exists, and its short name is returned? See https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/a76a4acf87952249b94f4be29614565541eb8c46/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/Repository.java#L876-L881

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55149/discussion-between-victorsc-and-vonc).