# Check out specific revision from Git repository with JGit

Tags: java, jgit

I am trying to use jGit to clone a repository and checkout a particular commit.

Assuming the commit hash is: 1e9ae842ca94f326215358917c620ac407323c81.

My first step is:

```
// Cloning the repository
    Git.cloneRepository()
        .setURI(remotePath)
        .setDirectory(localPath)
        .call();
```

I then found another question which suggested this approach:

```
git.checkout().
                setCreateBranch(true).
                setName("branchName").
                setUpstreamMode(CreateBranchCommand.SetupUpstreamMode.TRACK).
                setStartPoint("origin/" + branchName).
                call();
```

But I'm unsure how to link the two together?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You will have to clone the repository first, thus your first step was right:

```
Git.cloneRepository().setURI(remotePath).setDirectory(localPath).call();
```

To just checkout a commit by its id you can call `checkout` like this:

```
git.checkout().setName("<id-to-commit>").call();
```

But note that this will result in a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228760/fix-a-git-detached-head). To avoid this, you can tell `checkout` to create a new branch first that points to the commit and then checkout this branch.

```
git.checkout().setCreateBranch(true).setName("new-branch").setStartPoint("<id-to-commit>").call();
```

The API isn't very intuitive, but it does what it should.

Comment: @rüdiger-herrmann how do I delete the new-branch after the checkout?

Comment: @AnaSustic see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055688/delete-branch-with-jgit-not-working-as-expected

Comment: @Rüdiger Herrmann if I want to checkout particular path in a commit. Then how I can do that?

Comment: Have you tried using `addPath`, e.g. `git.setName("<commit-id>").addPath("path/to/file").call()`?