# Java: Check out specific revision from Git repository with JGit

Tags: java, eclipse, git, repository, jgit

I'd like to checkout a specific revision of a git repository with Java. I've found [JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/) to do thos task. A clone of the entire repo is already possible:

```
Git.cloneRepository();
```

However, I need a specific revision (not HEAD). How could this be achieved with JGit?

Comment: This has been answerd here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892748/jgit-checking-out-file/24893404#24893404 - the title of the question should probably be renamed to better match the content.

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry that I have produced a duplicate.