# Checkout a specific revision based on the commit date with JGit

Tags: java, git, version-control, jgit

I want to use the Java JGit library in order to retrieve previously committed revisions of a file. The file gets updated on a daily basis and I need to have access to the previous versions from a git repository.

I know how to checkout a specific revision by providing the commit hash of the revision I need, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892748/check-out-specific-revision-from-git-repository-with-jgit/24893404#24893404) with this command:

```
git.checkout().setName( "<id-to-commit>" ).call();
```

Currently I clone the repository, search for the most recent commit of that file and then checkout the revision. The process I have now is cumbersome as I would need to re-checkout the repository each time. I would rather just export a single file from a specific revision (of the master branch, for instance).

### Revision Log

Retrieve the revision log of the repository and get the commits of the file I am interested in.

```
 private static HashMap getRevisionsByLog(Repository repository, String filePath) {


    HashMap commitMap = new HashMap<String, DateTime >();


    Git git = new Git(repository);
    LogCommand logCommand = null;
    try {
        logCommand = git.log()
                .add(git.getRepository().resolve(Constants.HEAD))
                .addPath(filePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        for (RevCommit revCommit : logCommand.call()) {
            DateTime commitDate = new DateTime(1000L * revCommit.getCommitTime());
            // Store commit hash and date
            commitMap.put(revCommit.getName(),commitDate);
        }
    } catch (GitAPIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return commitMap;
}
```

### Most recent Revision

This code retrieves the most recent revision of the commits, which is before the date I am interested in:

```
 private static String getMostRecentCommit(HashMap<String, DateTime > commitMap, DateTime execDate){
    Iterator it = commitMap.entrySet().iterator();
    Map.Entry<String, DateTime> mostRecentCommit = null;

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        DateTime currentCommitDate = (DateTime) pair.getValue();

        if(mostRecentCommit==null && ((DateTime) pair.getValue()).isBefore(execDate)){

           mostRecentCommit = pair;
            }else if (currentCommitDate.isBefore(execDate)){
                System.out.println("Current date is before exec");
                if(currentCommitDate.isAfter(mostRecentCommit.getValue())){
                    System.out.println("Current date is before exec and after the most recent one");
                    mostRecentCommit=pair;
                }
            }

    }

    System.out.println("Current most recent:  " + mostRecentCommit.getKey() + " = " + mostRecentCommit.getValue());
    return mostRecentCommit.getKey();

}
```

### A Simple Test Application

In this application, I want to revert the working copy of the file to the state which it was before 2015-06-26T14:25:00.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    DateTime dt = new DateTime("2015-06-26T14:25:00");
    Date execDate = dt.toDate();

    String remotePath = "/media/Data/Gittest/repo/";
    String localPath="/tmp/localgit";

    // Clone repository
    try {
        Git.cloneRepository().setURI(remotePath)
                .setDirectory(new File(localPath)).call();
    } catch (GitAPIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Git git = null;
    try {
        git = Git.open(new File(localPath));
        Repository repo = git.getRepository();

        HashMap map = getRevisionsByLog(repo, "versuch.txt");

        String commitID = getMostRecentCommit(map,dt);

        System.out.println("Commit hash" +commitID);
        git.checkout().setName(commitID).call();



    } catch (IOException e) {
       ...
    }


}
```

### Questions

This is a very naive implementation, I am sure that JGit offers a more elegant way, but I could not find any hints. I would like to export a specific revision of one single file programmatically. I need to refer to a specific date, I want to fetch the revision which was valid during that date. The file it self gets updated quite often, nevertheless I need a mechanism to access the previous versions and use them as input for another process. What would be the best way of achieving this with Java and JGit?

## Solution based on the answer from Rüdiger Herrmann

The solution you proposed only works with the exact date/timestamp. Thus as you said in your answer, the solution only works if there is only one commit per day. As this is not guaranteed, I use a slightly different approach.

First, I retrieve all the commits from the file and sort them by date in a Treemap. The commits are sorted in a descending order, the most recent one is therefore last.

```
    /*
    * Get all commits of a file before a given date
    * */
    private TreeMap<DateTime,RevCommit> getAllCommitsBefore(Date execDate, String path){
    RevWalk walk = new RevWalk( this.repo );
    TreeMap<DateTime, RevCommit> commitsByDate = new TreeMap<DateTime, RevCommit>();
    try {
        walk.markStart( walk.parseCommit( this.repo.resolve( Constants.HEAD ) ) );

        walk.sort( RevSort.COMMIT_TIME_DESC);
        walk.setTreeFilter(PathFilter.create(path));

        for( RevCommit commit : walk ) {
            if ( commit.getCommitterIdent().getWhen().before(execDate) ) {
                DateTime commitTime = new DateTime(commit.getCommitterIdent().getWhen());
                commitsByDate.put(commitTime, commit);

            }
        }
        walk.close();
        System.out.println("Number of valid commits: " + commitsByDate.size());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return commitsByDate;
    }
```

Then, I can retrieve the most recent commit simply by retrieving the last commit in the TreeMap.

```
    public RevCommit getMostRecentCommit(Date execDate, String path){
    TreeMap<DateTime,RevCommit> allCommits = this.getAllCommitsBefore(execDate,path);
    RevCommit lastCommit = allCommits.lastEntry().getValue();
    System.out.println("Last entry: " + lastCommit.getName());
    return lastCommit;

    }
```

Then, I can retrieve the file of that revision and export it.

```
    public void retrieveFileFromCommit(String path, RevCommit commit, String outputPath){
    TreeWalk treeWalk  = null;
    try {
        treeWalk = TreeWalk.forPath(this.repo, path, commit.getTree());
        InputStream inputStream = this.repo.open( treeWalk.getObjectId( 0 ), Constants.OBJ_BLOB ).openStream();

        this.writeFile(inputStream,outputPath);
        treeWalk.close(); // use release() in JGit < 4.0

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

    /*
    * Write the stream to the disk
    * */
    private void writeFile(InputStream inputStream, String outputPath){
    OutputStream outputStream =
            null;
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputPath));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println("Done!");

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find a commit within a given date range and then read the contents of a specific file form that commit.

Assuming that there is only one commit per date, you can use a `RevWalk` to To get get the desired commit:

```
try (RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo)) {
  walk.markStart(walk.parseCommit(repo.resolve(Constants.HEAD)));
  walk.sort(RevSort.COMMIT_TIME_DESC);
  walk.setRevFilter(myFilter);
  for (RevCommit commit : walk) {
    if (commit.getCommitter().getWhen().equals(date)) {
      // this is the commit you are looking for
      revWalk.parseCommit(commit);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I am not entirely sure if the `revWalk.parseCommit(commit);` is necessary - it depends on how the `RevWalk` is set up. Try to run the code without parsing the commit and if the file is found, leave it at that.

Now that you have the desired commit, use a `TreeWalk` to obtain the content of the file:

```
try (TreeWalk treeWalk = TreeWalk.forPath(repository, fileName, commit.getTree())) {
  InputStream inputStream = repository.open(treeWalk.getObjectId(0), Constants.OBJ_BLOB).openStream();
  // use the inputStream
}
```

`fileName` holds the repository-relative path to the file in question.