# How to get all changed files since some commit in jGit?

Tags: java, git, jgit

TreeWalk allows to get all changes in single commit or in whole repository and checking changed files for each commit (by RevWalk) works really slow, about 2 minutes. Is there any method to walk through changed files and check in which commit they has been changed last time? Or other faster solution?
Here is my code for getting changed files from commit:

```java
TreeWalk treeWalk = prepareTreeWalk(commit, git.getRepository());
List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
while (treeWalk.next()) {
  if (!hasSimilar(treeWalk)) {
    files.add(treeWalk.getPathString());
  }
}
```

and for selecting commits (since some special):

```java
return Lists.reverse(StreamSupport.stream(
  git.log()
  .add(git.getRepository().resolve(branch.getName()))
  .call()
  .spliterator(), false)
    .filter(since(sinceCommit::equals))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Against wich other commit would you compare the 'since commit' to get the changed files? Would that be `HEAD`?

Comment: from some old commit until newest in current branch

Comment: I think your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785364/list-of-files-changed-between-commits-with-jgit To find the 'since' commit, I recommend using a plain `RevWalk` with a date filter like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074116/checkout-a-specific-revision-based-on-the-commit-date-with-jgit

Answer (score -1):

I know command line below, it will print the output within ms

git format-patch initial-commit --stdout > output.patch