# How to implement "git checkout <sha1-hash> ." in Jgit

Tags: jgit

I'm trying to implement a git repository with just one branch (no other branches allowed). So I tried to do something like the following:

```
     git rm -r -f *
     git checkout <hash> .

     *** make changes you want ***
    
     git stage -A
     git commit -m <commit message>
```

Which works totally fine for me when using it by the console.
However when using jgit I'm struggeling to implement the "git checkout <hash> ." part, since it doesn't allow me to do something like this:

```
git.checkout().setName("$previousCommitId .").call()
```

The resulting message of it would be the following:
 `org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidRefNameException: Branch name 1ff5273b10cdc61386ffe391560b7836da82a412 . is not allowed`

Comment: `setName` accepts a commit ID (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892748/check-out-specific-revision-from-git-repository-with-jgit). `$previousCommitId .` certainly isn't a valid commit ID. The error message indicates that you pass `<hash> .` (i.e. has plus space plus dot). Use the plain hash and it should work.

Comment: This won't work for me. I need the dot in the end. The difference is that checkout without the dot will result in checking out the revision, whereas the dot updates the files. I actually want to stay on the same revision and only update the files.

Comment: The dot is part of the pathspec. It seems `git.checkout().setName(<commit ID>).setAllPaths(true).call()` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sadly setAllPaths and setName are mutually exclusive. So I can only checkout (update) everything but not just the single revision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rüdiger Herrman I got closer to the solution. He was already pretty close. Since setName and setAllPaths are mutaly exclusive the only option to reach the goal seems to be:

```
    git.checkout().setStartPoint(commitHash).setAllPaths(true).call();
```